# removing an element from a list using recursion and pattern matching

Tags: recursion, f#, pattern-matching

Using recursion in F#, i am supposed to write a recursive function to remove an integer n from a list l.
The function takes int and iList and returns an iList (which is the list of integer)

this is what i have so far:

`let rec remove n l
match l with
| E -> failwith "Empty List"
| L(h,E) -> if (h=n) then 0 else h
| L(h,t) -> if (h=n) then remove n t else h + remove n t`

In the code above, i have it set up so that it returns the sum of the elements in the list instead of actual elements in the list after excluding the given integer n from the list.

I need help returning the remaining elements of the list after excluding the given integer n.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this using an accumulator parameter (`acc` in the code below). The `acc` parameter is used to carry the result of the previous call to the recursive function, thus building the final result. It's a common paradigm in functional programming. In this case we start `acc` with an empty list and add elements to it but skip when it matches `x`.

```
let rec remove x l acc =
    match l with
    | [] -> acc
    | h::t when x = h ->  List.append acc t
    | h::t -> remove x t (List.append acc [h])
```

Use it like this:

```
remove 1 [1;2;3] []
```

Another way to do it is by using `List.collect`:

```
let remove_use_collect x l =
    let helper y =
        if x = y then [] else [y]
    List.collect helper l
```

However I think it's important to understand the 1st method and how to use accumulator parameters, since it's quite common in functional programming, where you can't modify values. You'll find that a lot of the List module functions are implemented using an accumulator somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from sashang assumes the built-in F# `list` type.  Since the question seems to use a custom type with cases `E` and `L`, here's an answer that doesn't depend on the `List` module or type at all.  It also doesn't expose the accumulator as a top-level parameter, so callers don't need to worry about passing an initial value:

```
type ilist = E | L of (int * ilist)

let remove value list =
    let rec remove value acc = function
    | E -> acc
    | L (head, tail) when head = value -> tail |> remove value acc
    | L (head, tail) -> tail |> remove value (L (head, acc))

    list |> remove value E
```

As an important note, this function will effectively reverse the order of the list.  If you need the order of the list to be preserved, you can enhance the function to support that requirement.